Slack slash commands not receiving files posted
I created a slack app which uses the "Slash Commands" to call a Google Cloud Function.
I want the command to be sent with one file, but the information arriving to the Cloud Function doens't have any information about the file attached.
This is what I get in the Cloud Function from the request.form using python:
request.form: ImmutableMultiDict([('token', 'EUH4ykLWbPK4rEJ0IfubR6jh'), ('team_id', 'T07NZDHNURF'), ('team_domain', 'ALOALO'), ('channel_id', 'C07SRPL676J'), ('channel_name', 'developer_test'), ('user_id', 'U07NLL49L7M'), ('user_name', 'xpto'), ('command', '/uploadfiles'), ('text', ''), ('api_app_id', 'A07TM2KJD08'), ('is_enterprise_install', 'false'), ('response_url', 'https://hooks.slack.com/commands/T07NZDHNURF/7909887477990/W2FolbBasHC9SN2X8mAOjtXd'), ('trigger_id', '7939307245440.7781459776865.537c8ca1c877fadc24148302692cb9a7')])

Any idea on how to get the filenames and how can I access the files?
Thanks,
Rui
